# Programmatically connect to a Bluetooth headset from an Android application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am looking for a way to initiate the audio connection between the Android phone and my headset within my application. The idea is to simplify the connection process in such a way that the user doesn't have to go through the different settings menus anymore (Apps -> Settings -> Wireless & Networs -> Bluetooth settings).

Both devices are supposed to be already paired and the Bluetooth address of the headset to be known.

As far as I learned, the Bluetooth capabilities (available since version 2.0 of the Android SDK) are restricted to Bluetooth discovery and the connection of RFComm channels (host/client) between the Android phone and a Bluetooth device. Is there another way to request Bluetooth profiles on the Android system to initiate a connection to a known device from an app or is this impossible?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) class?  It seems like you can do everything you need via that class, unless I misunderstand the question.

As for initiating a connection to a specific device, won't the phone auto-pair with the known device once you enable bluetooth?

Comment: If I understand it correctly the BluetoothAdapter class gives me only control to a portion of Androids Bluetooth stack: with BluetoothAdapter you're certainly able to discover other devices and control the Bluetooth radio but it seems impossible to me to initiate a different connection than a RFComm link. Please correct me if I am wrong...

As for auto-pair: that works sometimes. Most if the time however, I find myself waiting for an auto-connection for a long time (with no success) and that is why I am rather interested in a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using follow code to get IBluetooth service, and it has sevral function including connect headset.

```
IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService("bluetooth");
if (b != null) {
        IBluetooth mBluetoothService = IBluetooth.Stub.asInterface(b);
    }
```

But, these apis are hidden for app level, and they are different on different android sdk version.You must comply the code in android whole source enviroment, or use reflection to access them.